# Using JMETER: "jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler" for Chrome Driver with Response Code 500

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am currently using the JMeter WebDriver Sampler for Chrome. I have tried with 89, 88 & 87 ChromeDriver.exe but it doesn't work properly. The Chrome browser launched and it's not displaying the Google website. Please advise and attached is my config and codes. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mainly because of syntax errors in your script:

1. You should not have whitespaces between class and function names

   ```
   WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
   WDS.browser.get('http://google.com')
   WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
   ```
2. I don't think you can use Beanshell with WebDriver Sampler, consider switching to JavaScript (which is default) or Groovy (which is [recommended scripting option since JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)) or at least if you want/have to you need to have semicolons in the end of lines and change quotation marks to `"` these .